# Are there any examples of use cases for body-parser post Express v4.16?

Tags: express, body-parser

I know that express removed body-parser and then reintroduced it in v4.16. Am I correct in understanding that body-parser is no longer needed, and I can directly use express.json / express.urlencoded instead? Or are there some specific cases in which I would still need to include body-parser?